# Unable to add window - windowmanager permission denied for this window type 2003 or 2006

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera, android-permissions

I'm working on a video recorder app with a background service. I'm getting these errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.justbackgroundcamera.BackgroundVideoRecorder@82e8d33 with Intent { cmp=com.example.justbackgroundcamera/.BackgroundVideoRecorder (has extras) }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@959f86d -- permission denied for window type 2003
```

Codes:

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT :
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    // layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

I think there are some errors about permissions. How do I get these permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem. We need some permissions when working with Android M and above. You can fix this problem with "draw over other apps" permission.

Add to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

WindowManager

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY :
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Add to your codes (onCreate)

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too few information. So make sure your application supports restriction for Android >= O. Because in this case you cannot start `Service`s in background without notification and `startForeground` call.

For ex.

```
final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
final String channelId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? getNotificationChannel(manager) : "";
final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
final Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .build();

startForeground(110, notification);
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm using the notifications. I knew I had a problem with the permissions. So I solved the problem.